# IntStream rangeClosed unable to return value other than int

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Why is this getting error? I thought `map` can return any value.

```
var s = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> |  Error: |  incompatible types: bad return type in method reference |
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to int |  var s =
>   IntStream.rangeClosed(1,
>   5).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()); |
>   ^-------------^

Comment: Note that this post is tagged [tag:java-8], but the `var` keyword is available from Java 9.

Comment: @MCEmperor (true) Java-10 precisely. Anyway, that's not of utmost importance for the current question and can be ignored unless someone actually tries to copy the same code to make it work under Java-8.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [**mapToObj**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj(java.util.function.IntFunction)):

```
var s = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[**map**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map(java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)) of `IntStream` can only map an `int` value to another `int` value. It accepts an `IntUnaryOperator` (which accepts an `int` and returns an `int`) as the mapper function, and returns an `IntStream`.

On the other hand, `mapToObj` allows you to map an `int` value to any reference type, and thus transform the `IntStream` to a `Stream<SomeReferenceType>`. It accepts an `IntFunction<? extends U>` (which accepts an `int` and returns a reference type) as the mapper function, and returns a `Stream<U>`.

Answer (score 6):

Use [mapToObj](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) instead :

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

While the aforementioned answers are correct and `mapToObj` is the idiomatic approach to proceed with, I think it's important to understand why the problem arises and thus in future cases, you'll know how to decipher the problem simply by going through the documentation.

it's a very important skill for a programmer to dig into the documentation when not understanding the workings of a specific method.

So, let's go through the relevant stream pipeline operations:

[`IntStream.rangeClosed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) returns an `IntStream` as per the documentation:

> Returns a sequential ordered IntStream from startInclusive (inclusive)
>   to endInclusive (inclusive) by an incremental step of 1.

invoking [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) on an `IntStream` is expected to return an `IntStream` as per the documentation:

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given
>   function to the elements of this stream.

As well as that it's important to note that the method declaration for `map` is as follows:

```
IntStream map(IntUnaryOperator mapper)
```

i.e. it takes a [**`IntUnaryOperator`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html) which in fact represents an operation on a **single int-valued operand that produces an int-valued result**.

However, you're passing a function `String::valueOf` which consumes an `int` as we're dealing with an `IntStream` and returns a `String`  thus not compliant with `IntUnaryOperator` and *this is the cause of the problem*.

Whenever you want to take a primitive stream specialization and perform some mapping function and in turn yield a `Stream<R>` as a result then `mapToObj` is the way to go.

`mapToObj` is declared as:

[`mapToObj(IntFunction<? extends U> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-)

`IntFunction` represents a function that accepts an int-valued argument and produces a result and this result is of type `R` which means you'll have a `Stream<R>` after the `mapToObj`.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could use [`IntStream.boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()) as :

```
var s = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5) // IntStream
                 .boxed() // Stream<Integer>
                 .map(String::valueOf) // Stream<String>
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

since the `IntStream` originally is a sequence of primitive int-values elements.

---

Another variant of performing such an operation would be :

```
var s = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5)
                 .boxed()
                 .map(a -> Integer.toString(a))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```